# how to get spirit's qi::as_string to work with repeat?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi, boost-spirit-lex

For some odd reason, I can't get `qi::as_string[]` to work with `repeat()[]`.

Parsing `std::string str = { "{ +100S+++ ;\n }" };`, I get the following **OUTPUT**

```
PLUS OR MINUS+
THREE PLUS OR MINUS
PARSED FINE
-------------------------
Parsing succeeded
-------------------------
```

which shows that parsing was ok, the first `+` was captured, but not the subsequent three `+++`.

**NOTE** I am just trying to get `three_plus_or_minus` to capture one to three pluses or minuses in a row as a string.  Alternative solutions that don't use `as_string[]` would be appreciated as well.

I apologize for the long listing, but I need to use both a lexer and a parser in my real code.

**CODE**

```
// --------------  Third Party  --------------
#include <boost/config/warning_disable.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/lex_lexertl.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_operator.hpp>

// --------------  C++ stdlib   --------------
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace boost::spirit;
using boost::phoenix::val;

enum token_ids
{
    ID_CONSTANT = 1000,
        ID_INTEGER,
        ID_TAG,
    ID_IDENTIFIER
};

template <typename Lexer>
struct example6_tokens : lex::lexer<Lexer>
{
    example6_tokens()
    {
        identifier = "[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*";
        constant   = "[0-9]+";

        tag           = "sl|s|l|tl|SL|S|L|TSL|"    
                                    "z|r|i|Z|R|I|"              
                                    "<>|><|<<>>|>><<|><><|<><>";

        this->self = lex::token_def<>('(') | ')' | '{' | '}' 
            | '=' | ';' | ':' | '+' | '-';

        this->self.add
        (constant,        ID_CONSTANT       )
        (tag,             ID_TAG            )
        (identifier,      ID_IDENTIFIER     )
        ;

        this->self("WS")
            =   lex::token_def<>("[ \\t\\n]+")
                |   "\\/\\*[^*]*\\*+([^/*][^*]*\\*+)*\\/"
                |   "\\/\\/[^\n]*"
                ;
    }
    lex::token_def<std::string>   identifier, tag;
    lex::token_def<unsigned int>  constant;
};

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <typename Iterator, typename Lexer>
struct example6_grammar
        : qi::grammar<Iterator, qi::in_state_skipper<Lexer> >
{
    template <typename TokenDef>
    example6_grammar(TokenDef const& tok)
        : example6_grammar::base_type(program)
    {
        using boost::spirit::_val;

        program
            =  +block
               ;

        block
            =   '{' >> *slsltl_stmt >> '}'
                ;

        plus_or_minus
                %=   ( qi::as_string[ qi::lit( '+' ) ] | qi::as_string[ '-' ])
                    [
                 std::cout << val("PLUS OR MINUS") << val( _1 ) << "\n"
                    ]
                        ;

        three_plus_or_minus
                %=   ( qi::as_string[ repeat(1,3)['+'] ] | qi::as_string[ repeat(1,3)['-'] ] )
                    [
                 std::cout << val("THREE PLUS OR MINUS") << val( _1 ) << "\n"
                    ]
                        ;

        slsltl_stmt
        =  (  - plus_or_minus
                    >> token(ID_CONSTANT) 
                    >> token(ID_TAG)
                    >> three_plus_or_minus
                    >> ';'
                )
                        [
                    std::cout << val("PARSED FINE") << "\n"
                        ]
                ;

        expression
            =   tok.identifier [ _val = _1 ]
                |   tok.constant   [ _val = _1 ]
                ;
    }

    typedef boost::variant<unsigned int, std::string> expression_type;

    qi::rule<Iterator, qi::in_state_skipper<Lexer> > program, block;
    qi::rule<Iterator, std::string(), qi::in_state_skipper<Lexer> > 
        plus_or_minus, three_plus_or_minus;
    qi::rule<Iterator, std::string(), qi::in_state_skipper<Lexer> > slsltl_stmt;
    qi::rule<Iterator, expression_type(), qi::in_state_skipper<Lexer> >  expression;
};

int
main( int argv, char* argc[] )
{
    typedef std::string::iterator base_iterator_type;
    typedef lex::lexertl::token<
    base_iterator_type, boost::mpl::vector<unsigned int, std::string>
    > token_type;

    typedef lex::lexertl::lexer<token_type> lexer_type;
    typedef example6_tokens<lexer_type> example6_tokens;
    typedef example6_tokens::iterator_type iterator_type;
    typedef example6_grammar<iterator_type, example6_tokens::lexer_def> example6_grammar;

    example6_tokens tokens;                         // Our lexer
    example6_grammar calc(tokens);                  // Our parser
    std::string str = { "{ +100S+++ ;\n }" };

    std::string::iterator it = str.begin();
    iterator_type iter = tokens.begin(it, str.end());
    iterator_type end = tokens.end();

    std::string ws("WS");
    bool r = qi::phrase_parse(iter, end, calc, qi::in_state(ws)[tokens.self]);
    if (r && iter == end)
    {
        std::cout << "-------------------------\n";
        std::cout << "Parsing succeeded\n";
        std::cout << "-------------------------\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "-------------------------\n";
        std::cout << "Parsing failed\n";
        std::cout << "-------------------------\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
    slsltl_stmt %=  /*....*/;
```

Instead of `slsltl_stmt =`. The use of semantic actions disables automatic attribute propagation.

(I haven't looked at the rest of your code yet. There may be more places where this/others things need adapting)

---

**Edit**

I did some more testing and think this does what you expected:

```
three_plus_or_minus
        =   (qi::as_string[ repeat(1,3)[qi::char_('+')] | repeat(1,3)[qi::char_('-')] ])
            [ std::cout << val("THREE PLUS OR MINUS") << _1 << "\n" ]
                ;
```

A question out-of-the-box though: why are you using a Lexer? Wouldn't it make sense to have a token for `+++`?

Comment: I originally had it in the lexer as a part of a large, complex token (came across as a string).  Then I tried breaking it down into individual tokens, but but I didn't know if `+++` would interact badly with the `+` showing up in `boost::spirit::lex::token_def<>` as the addition operator.  But with your suggestion, I will try retry.